# Python FastAPI runs in PyCharm in Debug Mode and on Docker but not when Run

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi, uvicorn

I have some weird behaviour with an API I am currently developing with PyCharm.
I already developed many REST-API with Python FastAPI successfully. But this time, I am facing some very weird behaviour of my application.

To test locally, I added in the main.py script the following line, which works fine for every other application I ever developed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("starting server with dev configuration")
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

The code runs when I set a breakpoint on line `uvicorn.run(...)` and then resume from there.

The code does also run, when I build the docker image and then run it on docker when I use the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

...

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--workers", "1"]
```

But when I run normally, uvicorn does not seem to boot as no messages are logged like I would expect:

```
INFO:     Started server process [6828]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The problem occurred, after I added Azure application insights handler.

Configuration of application insights:

```
import logging

from fastapi import Request
from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
from opencensus.trace import attributes_helper, samplers
from opencensus.trace.span import SpanKind
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer
from starlette.types import ASGIApp

HTTP_HOST = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_HOST"]
HTTP_METHOD = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_METHOD"]
HTTP_PATH = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_PATH"]
HTTP_ROUTE = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_ROUTE"]
HTTP_URL = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_URL"]
HTTP_STATUS_CODE = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["HTTP_STATUS_CODE"]
STACKTRACE = attributes_helper.COMMON_ATTRIBUTES["STACKTRACE"]

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AzureApplicationInsightsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app: ASGIApp, azure_exporter: AzureExporter) -> None:
        self._app = app
        self._sampler = samplers.AlwaysOnSampler()
        self._exporter = azure_exporter

    async def __call__(self, request: Request, call_next):
        tracer = Tracer(exporter=self._exporter, sampler=self._sampler)
        with tracer.span("main") as span:
            span.span_kind = SpanKind.SERVER

            response = await call_next(request)
            # does not seem to return a response

            span.name = "[{}]{}".format(request.method, request.url)
            tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_HOST, request.url.hostname)
            tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_METHOD, request.method)
            tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_PATH, request.url.path)
            tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_URL, str(request.url))
            try:
                tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_STATUS_CODE, response.status_code)
            except Exception:
                tracer.add_attribute_to_current_span(HTTP_STATUS_CODE, "500")
        return response
```

Added as middleware:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter

from app.startup.middleware.application_insights import AzureApplicationInsightsMiddleware
from app.startup.middleware.cors import add_cors
from config import app_config


def create_middleware(app: FastAPI) -> FastAPI:
    if app_config.appinsights_instrumentation_key is not None:
        azure_exporter = AzureExporter(connection_string=app_config.appinsights_instrumentation_key)
        app.middleware("http")(AzureApplicationInsightsMiddleware(app=app, azure_exporter=azure_exporter))
    app = add_cors(app)
    return app
```

Added handler to logger:

```
import logging
import sys
from logging import StreamHandler

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s",
                              datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

handler = StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string=connection_string)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I use the standard template, which works for all my other application but this time obviously it does not. I wonder, there might be an issue with maybe some of the installed modules I am using in `requirements.txt`:

```
fastapi
uvicorn
azure-servicebus
pymongo[srv]
pandas
numpy
jinja2
svgwrite
matplotlib
```

Has anyone faced the same problem yet?

changed host to `localhost` --> uvicorn server still not booting

Comment: Are you sure you're not already running uvicorn on that port in pycharm at the same time? What happens if you try to access the host/port-combination? Do you have a firewall active?

Comment: I do not get any response when trying to access the app with host/port-combination. To be sure this port was not blocked by any other instance i tried to run the app on a different port like 5001 or 5003. But this did not help. And I am also able to run the app in debug mode so I assume, there is no blocking from the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

if you are windows user, try use wsl path, because it help me

For example [image]